# XSLT - Calculate order total

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml as some kind of order form

```
<Results>
<form-type>orderform-B</form-type>
<data>
  <form-data>
    <field>
       <name>productid-1</name>
       <value>Yes</value>
    </field>
    <field>
       <name>productid-1-qty</name>
       <value>2</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>productid-3</name>
        <value>Yes</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>productid-4</name>
        <value>Yes</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>productid-4-qty</name>
        <value>2</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>product-type</name>
        <value>productid-5-xl</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>someother-field</name>
        <value>xyz</value>
     </field>
  </form-data>
</data>
</Results>
```

And the following xslt to calculate order total

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="pricelist">
    <item id="productid-1">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-2">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-3">5</item> 
    <item id="productid-4">5</item>
    <item id="productid-5-sm">5</item>
    <item id="productid-5-md">10</item>
    <item id="productid-5-xl">15</item> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="price" match="item" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="qty" match="field" use="name" />

<xsl:template match="/Results">
  <total>
      <xsl:variable name="charges">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="data/form-data/field[starts-with(name, 'productid-') or starts-with(value, 'productid-')]"/>

      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum($charges/charge)" />
   </total>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
   <xsl:variable name="price" select="key('price', (name, value), $pricelist)" />
   <xsl:variable name="qty" select="key('qty', name)" />
   <xsl:if test="$price">
     <charge>
        <xsl:value-of select="$price * (if($qty) then $qty/value else 1)"/>
     </charge>
   </xsl:if> 
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works for the above xml. But now I have the following variant xml document where if the order has less than or equal to 5 productid-6 then the total price for productid-6 is £30 and if the order has between 5 and 10 productid-6 then the the total price of productid-6 is £60. As you can see from the xml productid-6 is nested inside a child element.

```
<Results>
 <form-type>orderform-B</form-type>
 <data>
  <form-data>
    <field>
       <name>productid-1</name>
       <value>Yes</value>
    </field>
    <field>
       <name>productid-1-qty</name>
       <value>2</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>productid-3</name>
        <value>Yes</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>productid-4</name>
        <value>Yes</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>productid-4-qty</name>
        <value>2</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>product-type</name>
        <value>productid-5-xl</value>
     </field>
     <field>
        <name>someother-field</name>
        <value>xyz</value>
     </field>
     <field>
          <name>another-field</name>
          <children>
            <child>
              <field>
                  <name>productid-6</name>
                  <value>xyz</value>
               </field>
            </child>
            <child>
               <field>
                  <name>productid-6</name>
                  <value>abc</value>
               </field>
            </child>
            <child>
               <field>
                   <name>productid-6</name>
                   <value>123</value>
               </field>
            </child>
        </children>
      </field>       
  </form-data>
 </data>
</Results>
```

How can i modify the xslt to accommodate this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="pricelist" as="document-node()">
    <xsl:document>
      <items>
        <item id="productid-1">5</item> 
        <item id="productid-2">5</item> 
        <item id="productid-3">5</item> 
        <item id="productid-4">5</item>
        <item id="productid-5-sm">5</item>
        <item id="productid-5-md">10</item>
        <item id="productid-5-xl">15</item> 
      </items>
    </xsl:document>
  </xsl:variable>
  
  <xsl:key name="price" match="item" use="@id" />
  <xsl:key name="qty" match="field" use="name" />
  
  <xsl:template match="/Results">
    <total>
      <xsl:variable name="charges">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data/form-data/field[starts-with(name, 'productid-') or starts-with(value, 'productid-')]"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="productid-6-exists" select="data/form-data/field/children/child/field/name='productid-6'"/>
      <xsl:variable name="productid-6-value">
        <xsl:variable name="chargeCount" select="count($charges/charge)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$productid-6-exists and $chargeCount gt 5 and $chargeCount lt 11">
            <xsl:value-of select="'60'"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$productid-6-exists and $chargeCount lt 6">
            <xsl:value-of select="'30'"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum($charges/charge) + $productid-6-value" />
    </total>    
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:variable name="price" select="key('price', name, $pricelist)" />
    <!-- The qty key needs the current name + '-qty' -->
    <xsl:variable name="qty" select="key('qty', concat( name,'-qty'))" />
    <xsl:if test="$price">
      <charge>
        <xsl:value-of select="$price * (if($qty) then $qty/value else 1)"/>
      </charge>
    </xsl:if> 
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```